# How to put an app on the AWS Marketplace that requires S3 resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-marketplace

I have an application on an EC2 Instance that I wish to put on the AWS Marketplace. The application uses AmazonS3 and on startup requires users to enter an `Access Key`, `Secret Key`, and a `BucketName`. It then uses the Accekey, and secretkey to create a bucket (specified by `BucketName`). However, this isn't allowed on the AWS Marketplace.

> However, for AWS Marketplace,we require application authors to use AWS
>   Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles and do not permit the use
>   of access or secret keys.

**Question**

I am confused as to how to get around this and still put my AMI on the AWS Marketplace. My goal is for users to create their own S3 buckets in their own AWS Environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your customers can create [AWS IAM roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) with access to the required resources (S3 buckets), and allow your account to use those roles.

The reasoning behind this mechanism is that your customers can follow the [principle of least privilege](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) and limit access to very specific resources and actions on those resources (instead of providing unsecured / root access to their entire account)

Comment: So, in the instructions I should mention to the users to create an IAM role with S3FullAccess Policy and specify this role when starting my AMI? And additionally, in my AMI I should grab the credentials from the EC2 instance metadata?

Comment: @Anthony - Exactly. I'd follow a model like [Cloudberry](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/cloudberry-products-support-amazon-iam-roles) describes - your users will need to supply an IAM role when they create the instance, and that role should have a minimum set of permissions in order for your appliance to work. Your code can then rely on the metadata fallback behavior that I described in my answer to your other question and automatically use the permissions from the instance's role.

Comment: If you really need full access, then yes. If you don't need to create and delete buckets, there are more restrictive policies that can be used (which will give your customers greater confidence that any bugs on your side won't negatively impact their other S3 resources)